# I am working on a code that detects whether a circle has been filled/checked or not, using Python and OpenCV. Any help would be really appreciated

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am trying to build a code (it's a part of my senior project) that detects the circles in the following image, and checks which ones are checked/filled, with their corresponding location. Any help would be highly appreciated. I am still new to python and this whole computer vision thing.

[image: this is the image I am currently working on]

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: Only for that particular form ?

Comment: I still don't know how to start working with it, I have been working with similar codes (shape detection and similar stuff) but I still don't know how to work on this, if you can provide me with some tips or some samples or anything related to this, I'd be extremely grateful.

Comment: Yes, only for this specific form (I'm going to use a camera later on, which would take live photos of these printed forms and process them, the camera code is ready, I'm still trying to figure out a way to process this form in terms of tracking the fields and checking whether they're checked or not). Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by checking?  Filling circle with black color? You should give a sample which has checked circles. Try to be more clear also while asking what your problem is

Comment: I updated the image of the post, thanks again :) I will rephrase. I have some exam sheets that should be digitized. The exam sheets have the form of the photo I just posted. I am going to use a camera, that would take photos of the exam sheets (where a pen is used to mark the circles). Then the code takes these photos and processes them (as in extracts the student ID, which semester he's enrolled in, the course ID and his grade). But I am still new to CV and Python, I know the basics but I still don't know how to come up with a full code that would do the required tasks. Thanks again :)